# Does *will somebody something* exist?

Tags: verbs, will-would

From [this post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-role-of-the-ISA):

> ..., because it will you you more performance or power reduction or both.

the article use *will you you sth*. [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/) notify me that *you you* should be *you-you*, but I also don't understand. BTW, is the double *you* here just typo?

In [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/will), when *will* is used as a **verb**(not **modal verb**), I only see **will sth/sb to do**.

So, does **will somebody something** exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of the post to which you linked is clearly not a native English speaker, or a careful typist. The words you query are not proper English. The text quoted would make some kind of sense if the first 'you' of the pair were replaced by 'give'.

Comment: To comment further on the OP’s question, the phrase **will _give_ somebody something** makes total sense.